# issue with hide and show content plus changing image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide and show some content and it is working but i can not make the button image to change from Minus to Plus when I have to hide the content back to it's normal state.

Anu suggestions ? 
Here is my code until this moment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show-content img').click(function() {
        $('.hidden-content').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.default-plus').attr('src','https://s11.postimg.org/7w0jbixvz/hide_content.jpg');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-content">
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg" width="66" height="66" title="someText" alt="someText" class="default-plus">
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
```

thank you guys but what if I have several same divs and i want to press this button to show and hide content then all others divs which are the same are opening and closing their content. How can I isolate them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 classes with background images:

> ```
>  $('.default').toggleClass('plus minus')
> ```

#### UPDATE

OP requested multiple buttons independently functioning. Used the keyword `this` and `.parent()` and `.next()` to target `.hidden-content`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-content button').click(function() {
$(this).parent().next('.hidden-content').slideToggle("fast");
$(this).toggleClass('plus minus')
  });
});
```

```css
.default {
  width: 66px;
  height: 66px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0 none transparent;
}
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.plus {
  background: url(https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg)no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.minus {
  background: url(https://s11.postimg.org/7w0jbixvz/hide_content.jpg)no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-content">
  <button title="someText" class="default plus"></button>
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
<div class="show-content">
  <button title="someText" class="default plus"></button>
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
<div class="show-content">
  <button title="someText" class="default plus"></button>
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
<div class="show-content">
  <button title="someText" class="default plus"></button>
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, may I ask you to check the question again i forgot to ask one more think if I have multiple divs with same button when the button is pressed all other divs are showing and I do not want this. I Want to isolate them

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show-content img').click(function() {
        $('.hidden-content').slideToggle("fast");
        if ($('.default-plus').attr('src') == "https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg")  {
            $('.default-plus').attr('src','https://s11.postimg.org/7w0jbixvz/hide_content.jpg');
        }else {
            $('.default-plus').attr('src','https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg');
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-content">
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg" width="66" height="66" title="someText" alt="someText" class="default-plus">
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    // get the default Image source before clicking
    // also it will not change it will remain the default image source
    var toggleImageDefaultSrc = $('.default-plus').attr('src');

    $('#show-content img').click(function() {
      
      var iconSrc = toggleImageDefaultSrc;
         
        // if element is toggled change image source
        if($( ".hidden-content" ).is( ":hidden" )) {
          iconSrc = 'https://s11.postimg.org/7w0jbixvz/hide_content.jpg';
        }
      
        $('.hidden-content').slideToggle("fast");
      

        $('.default-plus').attr('src', iconSrc);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-content">
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg" width="66" height="66" title="someText" alt="someText" class="default-plus">
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show-content img').click(function() {
        var $plus = $('.default-plus');
        var $content = $('.hidden-content');

        if ($plus.hasClass('minus')) {
            $content.slideUp("fast");             
            $plus
                .removeClass('minus')
                .attr('src','https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg');
        } else {
            $content.slideDown("fast");
            $plus
                .addClass('minus')
                .attr('src','https://s11.postimg.org/7w0jbixvz/hide_content.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-content">
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg" width="66" height="66" title="someText" alt="someText" class="default-plus">
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use if condition inside the click event, and change the src of image like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show-content img').click(function() {
        $('.hidden-content').slideToggle("fast");
        if(!$('.hidden-content').is(':visible'))
        {
            $('.default-plus').attr('src','https://s11.postimg.org/7w0jbixvz/hide_content.jpg}); 
        }
        else
        {
            $('.default-plus').attr('src','https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg}); 
        }
});
```

Hope it should works, if not please change the if condition little bit, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In this cases, I recommend to use CSS instead of editing the image source.

At least I would have did it this way instead.

You should keep your JS as simple as possible to achieve something you want and this can arguably improve the overall performance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.default-plus').on('click', function() {
        $('.hidden-content').slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    });
});
```

```css
.default-plus {
  display: block;
  width: 66px;
  height: 66px;
  background: url('https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 66px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.default-plus.clicked {
  background-image: url('https://s11.postimg.org/7w0jbixvz/hide_content.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-content">
  <div class="default-plus"></div>
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running this code.Hope it works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show-content img').click(function() {
        $('.hidden-content').slideToggle("fast");
        if($('.default-plus').attr('src') == 'https://s11.postimg.org/7w0jbixvz/hide_content.jpg')
        {
           $('.default-plus').attr('src','https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg');
        }
        else
        {
          $('.default-plus').attr('src','https://s11.postimg.org/7w0jbixvz/hide_content.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-content">
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/40x58yeq7/show_content.jpg" width="66" height="66" title="someText" alt="someText" class="default-plus">
  <h3>How to Sign-In on the Device</h3>
  <p>This is a subtext, if needed</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nisi maxime, sapiente iste nostrum assumenda, deserunt. Repellendus commodi labore eligendi, ipsum inventore reiciendis. Ipsum voluptatum cumque consequuntur error id quidem.</p>
</div>
```